# use maximum picture size patchwork grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, patchwork

on my patchwork grid images are not using the the maximum space possible. Is there an easy way to specify that patchwork should use all whitespace for the image?

Thank you very much in advance!

BR

Answer (score 0):

A better option could be using `background_image` from the `ggpubr` package so you can simply plot both side by side with p1+p2 like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(png)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggpubr)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) 
t1 <- kable(mtcars[1:10, c('mpg', 'disp')]) %>% 
  kable_styling() %>%
  save_kable('table1.png')
your_table <- readPNG('~/Downloads/table1.png')
p2 <- ggplot() + background_image(your_table) + coord_fixed()
p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Great iea thanks!! The only problem is, that the picture has a pretty wide grey border although I used exactly your code. Do you have an idea why is that?

Comment: @immuen, Could you please share your code and output in your question above?

Comment: It's exactly yours. Just the picture not filling the whole size of the plot.

Comment: And as provided in your sample, that readability of the table is compromised by the strange resulution or whatever in the table after reimporting it as png. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: another problem is that although i use coord_fixed the image keeps changing ratios.